# owl carousel css class not working in react app

Tags: css, class, owl-carousel

trying to add client testimonial section in website, owl carousel  not working after import and insert dependencies

```
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          <div className="col-lg-8">
            <div className="owl-carousel testimonials-carousel wow fadeInUp">
              
                <div className="testimonial-item">
                  <img
                    src={Testm1}
                    className="testimonial-img"
                    alt=" Client Testimonial"
                  />
                  <h3>rrrrrrrrrrrrr G</h3>
                  <h4>Ceo &amp; Founder</h4>
                  <p>
                    iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
                  </p>
                </div>

                <div className="testimonial-item">
                  <img
                    src={Testm2}
                    className="testimonial-img"
                    alt="Client Testimonial"
                  />
                  <h3>sssssssss K</h3>
                  <h4>Project Manager</h4>
                  <p>
                    pppppppppppppppppppppppppp
                  </p>
                </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

installed owl carousel as well as an import  jquery plugin

Comment: Any console error?

Comment: No console error